# PHP cURL request return 401, but works with Postman

Tags: php, web-services, curl, postman

If I execute the Webservice call with Postman with these parameters:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: xxxx
Body: json
```

The Webservice return successfully a JSON.

So, I generated the code with the Postman and paste it on PHP:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "url",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "json",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "cookie: xxxx",
    "postman-token: 7c771f8e-5c87-1d27-64f3-bdb92bba6a19"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

And the Webservice is returning an error 401. But it's working when I execute it on Postman.
What am I doing differently from Postman?

Comment: I've wrote a [crawling](https://github.com/w3zone/crawler) package may helps you in your problem, however you have to provide some additional details about your problem like the url you are trying to crawl , often the json requests needs the important header `Content-Length`

Comment: Hey, @HassanAhmed I could made it! Thanks a looot for your help. You can send a answer telling about the cookie and I will accept it!

Comment: congrats my friend :) good luck

Comment: Make sure if the auth header is in uppercase or lowercase, review the logs fo the authorizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 error code is usually been because some authorize issues :-

> [401 Unauthorized](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
>
> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If
>   the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401
>   response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
>   credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the
>   prior response, and the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the
>   entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include
>   relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is
>   explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access
>   Authentication"

which is mean that you are facing problems in authentication your request

often this will be fixed by **simulating** the web request

for example :-

assume that you have some page which login is needed to access to it ,

then you will have two requests you should do

1- post some login authentication data
2- send the cookies which returned from the first request , to the second request header

you will need to read more about cookies in [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) in php manual pages

specially `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIE` options

Comment: An important reminder: postman was returning successfully because of the cookies. After cleaning it up I started to receive the same error!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In postman it was working but through curl it was giving **401** error.

Now it is working for me with below code. I have used **base64_encode** for username and password.

Manual Page Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password), ]);  
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
echo "<br/>http status code is ".$status_code;
```

**Output:**

```
http status code is 200
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** the following line from your .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

It worked for me!